# Finding the lowest value before an increment in a list (and update it)

Tags: java

Imagine there's a list of objects with two columns, *Value* and *Lowest Value*. I would like to get the lowest value in *Value* column before it detects an increment and add it to the *Lowest Value* column in current row and row before it (if its empty).

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IraDM.png)

Based on the image above, the lowest value for the first three elements (before increment) is 1. I would then have to add it to the *Lowest Value* column.

Below is an unfinished code of mine, not sure how I would go about doing next.

```
public class TestClass {

    private int value;
    private int lowestValue;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getLowestValue() {
        return lowestValue;
    }

    public void setLowestValue(int lowestValue) {
        this.lowestValue = lowestValue;
    }   

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        ArrayList<TestClass> al = new ArrayList<TestClass>();
        int temp = 0;

        // create list (example)
        tc.setValue(3);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(2);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(1);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(3);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(2);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(3);
        al.add(tc);

        // process
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

            // assign value to temp (to compare later on)
            if (i == 0) {
                temp = al.get(i).getValue();
            }


            if (i > 0 ) {
                // if temp value is lower than current element value, reverse loop to update the lowest value variable in list
                if (temp < al.get(i).getValue()) {
                    for (int j = i; j >= 0 && j <= i; j--) {
                        System.out.println("i: " + i + ", j: " + j);
                        if (al.get(j).getLowestValue() != 0) {
                            al.get(j).setLowestValue(temp);
                        }
                    }
                    temp = al.get(i).getValue();
                } else if (temp >= al.get(i).getValue()) {   // unfinished part
                    temp = al.get(i).getValue();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `before it detects an increment` from what? Your code determines when the increment happens.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to do? Base on the image you will input a lowestvalue from temporary value, and when the temporary value is equal or less than to value the temporary value will increment, is that right?

Comment: Voting to close because no specific question was asked. "how I would go about doing next" is not specific.

Comment: @DevilsHnd That list is just a scenario. Value 1 (index 2) jumping to 3 (index 3) is considered as an increment. Also value 2 to 3 (index 4 - 5).

Comment: @Francisaskquestion I've added some comments to the code above. Basically if the temp value is more than current element value, it should skip until it finds a bigger number.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was cleaner to reset the value in the array list using a .set() rather than a .get(). I also found it easiest to track the next index to set and then set things by going forward until one before the position of the increment.
I also built in some methods (constructors and a print) to simplify pieces in the main part.
I tried to not nest things too deep by using continue. It also took some care to set the things beyond the last increment, especially since temp might not be holding the lowest value (I think), so instead I used the last value.

One thing to notice is that if things are not increasing in a particular run, the last value is the lowest (there may be a tie, but still).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestClass {

private int value;
private int lowestValue;
TestClass() {
    //default constructor
}
TestClass(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
TestClass(int value, int lowestValue) {
    this.value = value;
    this.lowestValue = lowestValue;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getLowestValue() {
    return lowestValue;
}

public void setLowestValue(int lowestValue) {
    this.lowestValue = lowestValue;
}

public void printTestClass() {
    System.out.println("For this item, value = " + this.getValue() + " and lowestValue = " + this.getLowestValue());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {


    ArrayList < TestClass > al = new ArrayList < TestClass > ();
    int temp = 0;
    int[] intArray = new int[] {
        3,
        2,
        1,
        3,
        2,
        3
    };
    //create list
    for (int c: intArray) {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(c);
        al.add(tc);
    }
    int nextIndexToSet = 0; //where we set lowest value
    boolean firstValueInThisRun = true; //nothing to compare to preceding it

    // process
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        if (firstValueInThisRun) {
            temp = al.get(i).getValue();
            firstValueInThisRun = false;
            continue; //because we could not possibly have an increment yet
        }
        //still here, check for an increment
        if (temp >= al.get(i).getValue()) {
            temp = al.get(i).getValue(); //set to the new lower value, or to itself
            continue; //because no increment found so nothing more to do yet
        }
        //still here, then there was an increment
        for (int j = nextIndexToSet; j < i; j++) {
            TestClass tc = new TestClass(al.get(j).getValue(), temp);
            al.set(j, tc);
            System.out.println("j = " + j + " i = " + i);
        }
        nextIndexToSet = i;
        firstValueInThisRun = true;


    } //closes outer for
    //check if anything still unset
    if (nextIndexToSet < al.size()) {
        for (int j = nextIndexToSet; j < al.size(); j++) {
            TestClass tc = new TestClass(al.get(j).getValue(), al.get(al.size() - 1).getValue());
            al.set(j, tc);
        }
    }
    //print the array list to make sure
    Iterator < TestClass > al_Iter = al.iterator();
    System.out.println("Elements in array list are : ");
    while (al_Iter.hasNext()) {
        al_Iter.next().printTestClass();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your code later. I've posted my solution, looks okay so far.

Comment: Yes, it looks like what I did with nextIndexToSet, you did with tempInd. But you managed to handle things entirely within the loop, without needing to fill in the last bit after -- nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for the time being. The output seems correct, however do point out if there's any mistake, thanks

```
public class TestClass {

    private int value;
    private int lowestValue;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getLowestValue() {
        return lowestValue;
    }

    public void setLowestValue(int lowestValue) {
        this.lowestValue = lowestValue;
    }   

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        ArrayList<TestClass> al = new ArrayList<TestClass>();
        int temp = 0;
        int tempInd = 0;

        // create list (example)
        tc.setValue(3);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(2);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(1);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(3);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(2);
        al.add(tc);
        tc = new TestClass();
        tc.setValue(3);
        al.add(tc);

        // process
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                al.get(0).setLowestValue(al.get(0).getValue());
                temp = al.get(i).getValue();
            }

            if (i > 0 ) {
                if (al.get(i).getValue() < temp) {
                    for (int j = i; j >= tempInd; j--) {
                        al.get(j).setLowestValue(al.get(i).getValue());
                    }
                    temp = al.get(i).getValue();
                } else if (al.get(i).getValue() >= temp) {
                    al.get(i).setLowestValue(al.get(i).getValue());
                    tempInd = i;
                    temp = al.get(i).getValue();
                }
            }
        }

        // updated list
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("al i: " + al.get(i).getValue() + ", lv: " + al.get(i).getLowestValue());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: else if (al.get(i).getValue() >= temp) could just be "else" (not a mistake, just a bit not needed)